# Docker Commit/Push not including files copied to container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to publish a docker container that contains the code from my .NET Core application in it.  I am able to build the container locally and run everything without a problem. I can login to the container and see that all my code exists in the /app directory.

I want to push this container up to a registry so I then do a `docker commit` and a `docker push` of those changes and all appears to work.  However when I pull down the image the /app directory is empty so the application does not the work.

Anyone know why this does not work and what I should be doing?

Is their a better way to get a container image with code into a registry?

For reference here is the DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY MyApplication/MyApplication.csproj MyApplication/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyApplication
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.dll"]
```

Comment: Where are copying the files from? The `COPY --from=publish` indicates a multistage build but there are no other stages in your Dockerfile. Are you copying the files from your local machine or from another Docker image?

Comment: Sorry I truncated the Dockerfile but yes it is a multi-stage build.  I added the full Dockerfile to the message above

Comment: You build and publish to the same directory. Have you tried different directories? Or removing the build command and let publish do the build?

Comment: I have but it did not seem to make a difference.  The container that is created by the `docker build` command has the code and works its only after the `docker commit` and `docker push` that the container no longer contains the code

Comment: What is the reason for the `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base` and `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build`? The default that VS provides would be `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build`

Comment: same problem, any solutions?